# Change XAML on click inside a bound gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-10-universal

we are developing an in-house Windows 10 app for time tracking. We are not extremely familiar with it but have it almost built. The question is how do we change the content of a single selected item inside a gridview.

XAML code

```
<Page
    x:Class="xxxxx.AllJobs"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:xxxxx"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="gridAllJobs" Background="White">
        <GridView x:Name="gridViewJobs" Margin="5,120,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="JobPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Background="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" Tapped="JobPanel_Tapped">
                        <local:DefaultContent/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Jobs" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="63" Width="124" FontSize="48"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblTime" Margin="0,10,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="8:00:00" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Right" Padding="2,2,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" Height="50"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtEmployee" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,67,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="48" Width="223" FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Right" Padding="2"/>
        <Image x:Name="imgClockOut" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="115" Margin="0,0,238,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Source="Assets/clockout.png" Tapped="imgClockOut_Tapped"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

When the user selects an individual job, we want the  to be replaced with another resource (or maybe there is a better way to do this). But just for that one job.

DefaultConent is a usercontrol

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="xxxxx.DefaultContent"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:xxxxx"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="150"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

        <StackPanel x:Name="OuterPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White" Margin="20,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="LeftPanel" Margin="5" Width="225">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtProdID"  Text="{Binding ModuleID}" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkBlue" Padding="2" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtJobID" Text="{Binding JobID}"  Padding="2" FontSize="10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemID}"  Padding="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei" FontSize="20"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}" Padding="2" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="DividerPanel" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="LightGray" Width="1"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Width="95" Margin="20,5,20,10">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CalcQty}" TextAlignment="Right" Padding="2" FontSize="24"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OprID}" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="2,38,2,2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="JobStatus">
            <local:NotStarted/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And we want to replace that content with buttons. We are completely open to any ideas. We may be going about this completely wrong. I'm sure it is something simple and we just cannot find the answer.

Thanks in advance.

**Update.**

I've been able to bind a new property on click. When I add this property as a text block, it does update on the click. However, the "Setter" does not seem to be doing anything. The value of my text changes. But the properties of the panel are not changing.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LeftPanel" Margin="5" Width="225">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtProdID"  Text="{Binding ModuleID}" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkBlue" Padding="2" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtJobID" Text="{Binding JobID}"  Padding="2" FontSize="10"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemID}"  Padding="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei" FontSize="20"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}" Padding="2" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsClicked}" Padding="2" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel x:Name="DividerPanel" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="LightGray" Width="1"/>

                            <StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Width="95" Margin="20,5,20,10">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CalcQty}" TextAlignment="Right" Padding="2" FontSize="24"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OprID}" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="2,38,2,2"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualState>
                                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                            <StateTrigger x:Name="CurrItem" IsActive="{Binding Path=IsClicked}"/>
                                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LeftPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Have you seen anything about setters and triggers like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45802145/6797752 ?

Comment: I cannot get that to work. <StateTriffer IsActive="True"/> Appears to alway be true. And it affects every instance of the panel. Nothing changes when I click just one panel.

Comment: Since you already have a usercontrol in your data template, you can encapsulate all the UI logic within it. I'd create two contents, reveal only one first and *flip* to the other when clicked/tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several reasons why your UI isn't updating.

1. You can apply a mode to your binding may force the data back.
2. But more importantly, are you implementing the the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, this allows the updated property to be sent back to the ui as it updates.

To do this add the interface of  `: INotifyPropertyChanged` to your class housing your data that needs updated, then it will prompt for you to add your implementation.

Then update your properties to hit the property back.

Example:

```
    public class DemoCustomer : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

//NotifyPropertyChanged

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
            // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
            // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

    //Property:

    public string CustomerName
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.customerNameValue;
                }

                set
                {
                    if (value != this.customerNameValue)
                    {
                        this.customerNameValue = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Referenced example from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx